# How to achieve space between table cells in HTML email

Tags: css, html-email

Trying to get a specific layout working across multiple email clients, but I despise HTML emails as many other devs do and I'm finding it a nightmare.

Here's what I'm aiming for:

[image: Dates]

This is the code I've got so far (it's twig but pure HTML / CSS is fine if anyone can help):

```
{% set tdstyle = 'color: #333333; text-align: center; line-height: normal; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1); border: 1px solid rgba(201, 201, 201, 1); border-radius: 0; padding: 16px;' %}
{% set tdstyleavailable = 'color: #fff; background-color: rgba(39, 174, 96, 1);' %}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="weeks">
    {% for rowIndex in 0..3 %}
        <tr>
            {% for cellIndex in 0..3 %}
                {% set week = weeks[4 * rowIndex + cellIndex] %}
                    <td {% if week.available %}class="available" bgcolor="rgba(39, 174, 96, 1)" style="{{ tdstyle }} {{ tdstyleavailable }}"{% else %}bgcolor="rgba(242, 242, 242, 1)" style="{{ tdstyle }}"{% endif %}>
                        <h3 style="font-size: 8px; margin: 2px;">W/C {{ week.startDate|date('jS M Y') }}</h3>
                        <h4 style="margin: 2px;">{{ week.available ? 'Available' : 'Unavailable' }}</h4>
                    </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

But there's no spacing between the cells:

[image: broken]

Answer (score 0):

Your `cellspacing="0"` on the table is removing the space between cells. Try:

```
<table cellpadding="" cellspacing="10" border="0" class="weeks">
```

Also make sure that you don't have a CSS rule that is applying `border-spacing: 0` or `border-collapse: collapse` to your table, either of which would override its `cellspacing` attribute.

Comment: Weirdly that doesn't appear to have made any difference. Would a parent table override the cellspacing on the child? :/

Comment: No. Here is a demo with your styles CSS applied, and a nested table: https://jsfiddle.net/t0ddzrzn/ One possibility is that you have a CSS style which is not shown in your question that is overriding the cell spacing. Setting `border-collapse: collapse;` on a table would override its `cellspacing` attribute, for instance.